# Parametric equations and specifications of a logarithmic triskelion (triple spiral)

Tags: geometry, matlab, parametric, visualization

There is a post in this forum that shows how to create an Archimedean triskelion:

[Parametric equations and specifications of a triskelion (triple spiral)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651772/parametric-equations-and-specifications-of-a-triskelion-triple-spiral)

```
Nsp = 3; % Number of spirals
Nwh = 2; % Number of whirls in each spiral

a = 1; % Scale
dt = 0.0001;

hold on

for n = 0:(Nsp - 1)

   x0 = a * cos(2 * pi * n / Nsp);
   y0 = a * sin(2 * pi * n / Nsp);
   t1 = 2 * pi * Nwh - pi / Nsp + pi / 2;
   t2 = t1 + 2 * pi / Nsp;
   c = a * sin(pi / Nsp) * 2 / pi / (1 + 4 * Nwh);

   t = dt:dt:t2;
   r = c * t;

   x = x0 + r .* cos(t + 2 * pi * n / Nsp);
   y = y0 + r .* sin(t + 2 * pi * n / Nsp);
   plot(x, y, '.b')

   inds = t <= t1;
   t = t(inds);
   r = r(inds);
   x = x0 + r .* cos(t + pi + 2 * pi * n / Nsp);
   y = y0 + r .* sin(t + pi + 2 * pi * n / Nsp);
   plot(x, y, '.r')

end
xis equal
axis off
```

I am looking for the parametric form of a logarithmic triskelion, in case somebody could assist that would be of great help...

Thank you!